# groovyc and java class file Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

Tags: java, groovy

I am learning a groovy HelloWorld

this is HelloWorld.groovy

```
println "Hello, World"
```

groovyc HelloWorld.groovy

generate HelloWorld.class

java -Xdiag -cp groovy-2.4.21/embeddable/groovy-all-2.4.21.jar HelloWorld

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

but  I execution ： groovy HelloWorld.groovy ，The right to perform

Comment: Your classpath is incorrect.  Assuming that `HelloWorld.class` is in the current directory, try this:  `java -Xdiag -cp .:groovy-2.4.21/embeddable/groovy-all-2.4.21.jar HelloWorld`

Comment: The right to perform , thanks very much!

Comment: Cool.  Now I suggest you read through the Java documentation on the classpath (e.g. in `man java`) to understand your mistake.  It is important that any dev using Java should understand how the classpath works, and the correct way(s) to set it.

Comment: you are right !  I before set CLASSPATH in /etc/profile , It contains current dir. but java -cp  make CLASSPATH  disabled , I do not understand Java documentation on the classpath

Comment: Keep reading.  The documentation *explains* that `-cp` takes precedence over the `CLASSPATH` variable.